# Is it class imbalance? Test set gives very high proportion of a class which was in minority in train set

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, modeling, unbalanced-classes

I want to investigate why am I seeing the below described phenomena. I welcome all the logical explanation which might hint towards what is happening.

So I have a dataset which contains two classes:

- 0
- 1

So its a basic binary classification. I have used algorithms such as:

- Logistic Regression
- Decision Tree
- Random Forest
- Gradient Boosting

I did a train-test split just to see if my model is overfitting or not. The train data contains class 0 which is 85% of the data and class 1 which is 15%. The train accuracy I achieved is about 90% and the test accuracy is about 89%.
But when I am predicting it on real-test set, I am getting weird proposition of classes. I was expecting class 0 and class 1 proportion to be around what it was in train set that is 85% to 15% or nearby. But after predictive modelling I am getting the ratio as 60%:40% for class 0 and class 1.

Now I know for a fact that the proportion cannot be that much as the data which I am classifying cannot have class 1 so high. I have tried thinking of what could be the reason but cannot come up with anything. 
Since its a test set I cannot verify it, but only assume that what I am getting is right. 
I am confused whether to use this analysis or not. If anyone can please shed some light on what am I doing wrong, would be great. Please dont criticize my post as I tried explaining it to my best ability.

EDIT:

Also, one point to add here is, different algorithm such as logistic, random forest etc I am getting different proportions. For ex Decision tree is giving me 30 % Class 1, Logistic is inflating it to 66 %, Random is giving 40%.

EDIT 2:

I tired something new. So I had 5 independent variables which i was using to predict. I tried removing 1 of them and then the class proportion went from 60% to 10%, something what it should be. I did random removals and every time the proportion changes where as the accuracy for train and validation remains the same. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) What do you mean by real-test set vs test set? real-test set being the one where you do not know the labels? It may be the case that the class distribution from that real-test set is not the same as the one in your training and validation sets?

Comment: Thank you Tom. Yes real test set is the one which I don't know the labels for. I am trying to see the distribution of data using Visualization just to see if the underlying data varies or not. That may be a cause of this.. But the problem which I am facing is that using different algorithm such as logistic, random forest etc I am getting different proportions. For ex Decision tree is giving me 30 % Class 1, Logistic is inflating it to 66 %, Random is giving 40%. So I think the underlying data may not have to do anything with it. Is there anything I am missing building the model here?

Comment: What do you mean by "Since its a test set I cannot verify it"?  You should be able to verify on the test set.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, I don't recommend using only accuracy as your success metric for imbalanced datasets. Support it with metrics like precision, recall, etc. For example, a 60-40 % separation in your test set might correspond to 75 % accuracy (i.e. know 60 of 85 as Class 1, and the other 40 would include the remaining 15 Class 2 samples)

For your case, there might be the following cases:

1) You didn't train & validate your algorithms very well.

2) Your *real test set* class distribution is not the same as your *training/test set* distributions as @Tom suggests.

3) Most ML methods assumes your training & test sets come from the same underlying population. When this is not true, i.e. your *real test set* is coming from another distribution/population; the classical ways of learning fail. This is not a trivial problem, and there are [theses](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.427.8969&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for dealing such issues.

Comment: OK so i tired something new. So I had 5 independent variables which i was using to predict. I tried removing 1 of them and then the class proportion went from 60% to 10%, something what it should be. I did random removals and every time the proportion changes where as the accuracy for train and validation remains the same. Why is this happening ?

Comment: If 10 % is your class 0, it's not as it should've been, right? What are your classifiers' proportions for training & validation?

Comment: 10% for training and 9.8% for test, but I want to know why different algo gives different proportion and also why removing some variables gives me different proportion. Any idea ?

Comment: First of all, your different algorithms is apparently learning differently. Have you done hyper parameter tuning for all of them with a validation set? Maybe some of them are not trained very well.